# self-contained/serverless nosql databases

Tags: c#, wpf, nosql

I want to develop a standalone WPF client application with NO-SQL database.

Are there any self-contained / serverless / zero-configuration NO-SQL databases?

Alternatively, are there any NO-SQL databases that can be configured to deploy and run on a "client-side"? meaning totally automatically without having to manually install/configure them?

Comment: Try this: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/install/windows.html

Comment: @Boynux thanks. the big issue for me here is the huge amount of dependcies it requires. basically I want my app to be installed via a simple installation wizard. I'd like to minimize the amount of 3rd party softwares I'd be installing along-side..

Comment: Unfortunately the only options for `no-sql` that I can think of are, `files` and **Windows registry**. Those two don't need any setup.

Comment: @Boynux basically I'm looking for the "NO-SQL version" of SQLite

Comment: http://www.unqlite.org/ Here is something that you might be interested in.

Comment: And SDK for C#: https://github.com/majimenezp/System.Data.Unqlite

Comment: Alternatives are Tokyo Cabinet, Berkeleydb, Upscaledb (http://upscaledb.com - recommended, but i am biased because I wrote it). These databases are embedded in your application. No installation/configuration required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one that is written entirely in c#: http://siaqodb.com/